# MysqlConnector datatime binding variables

Tags: c#, .net, mysql

I'm using MySQL Connector to retrieve data from a mySQL database to a .NET app.
Here's my code :

```
DateTime syncStart = ....
DateTime syncFinish = ....
string Sql = "select * from orders where created_on > @SYNC_START_DATE and created_on <= @SYNC_FINISH_DATE"
myCommand = new MySqlCommand(Sql, conTrace);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SYNC_START_DATE", syncStart);
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SYNC_FINISH_DATE", syncFinish);

myDataReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

This query should return a bunch of rows, but instead the reader returns nothing
I've tried this query but insted filtering by date, I've filtered by id, binding the parameters in the same way and this worked.
It seems that it doesn't work when I use dateTime parameters.
Can anybody help me with this problem ?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you run a trace to see what the actual SQL being executed is? We need this to make sure that the SQL parameters are being added correctly

Comment: off-topic, but you might like to know that MYSQL has a `BETWEEN` syntax which allows you do something like `WHERE field BETWEEN low_value AND high_value`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `between`:

```
SELECT * FROM ORDERS WHERE created_on BETWEEN @SYNC_START_DATE AND @SYNC_FINISH_DATE
```

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp